# are color and dimension resources necessar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, localization, colors

In Android is it necessary to define the colors and dimensions as xml resources in res directory as opposed to just directly specifying the color code/dimension in the layout xml files.I understand with strings you define them in resources for localization.What about for these 2?

Comment: You don't have to, but it is much easier to have all your colors in one place. Imagine if you have to replace the color of all black textviews. Then you would have to go through all your layout-files and change the values, compared to just changing it once in the color.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not necessary, but it may help you in many situations, ie. if you want to change the textcolor of all your textviews, you only need to change it in your "color"-file.

Comment: Well, actually you can compare it with the use of the strings-file. If you want to change your application to support other languages, then you have all the strings at one place. It is excatly the same with your colors, dimentions etc. You only have to change things one place.

Answer (score 0):

is no necessary to have them in xml, but it's more useful like that, you write less code if you want different colors for different screen sizes and it's a standard... there are a lot of benefits of using xml...